# How to synchronize microphysics.js between clients?

Tags: javascript, networking, node.js, socket.io, physics

[Microphysics.js](https://raw.github.com/jeromeetienne/microphysics.js/master/codeflow/physics.js) is a javascript library that creates a world with 3d spheres and AABB boxes, enabling acceleration and collisions. Is it possible and practical to synchrone a world hosted on a node.js server between clients using sockets.io? What are general guidelines for programming it, optimizing for low latency?

The simplest implementation I could think of is: send periodically information containing position, speed and acceleration of each object near the client, then adjust it for message arrival time (ping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes basically you must have a live streaming data between clients with positions directions and everything that " moves ". 
Watching every object and sending every change of it to the other user is what you should be using.

I don't know how this could help you but good luck coding because you have some work to do.

Comment: But can I program it to send position+velocity+acceleration info every second for everyone or should I worry about optimizing for areas and sending the minimal data possible?

Comment: If you have a lot of clients you should just send the event that triggered an object to move and trigger it on the other clients. Sending every piece of info ( position, velocity, acceleration) is kind of a killer, is like rendering a 3D movie on every client without codecs.